# calling .net 2.0 web service only from localhost

Tags: vb.net, web-services

Is it possible in .net 2.0 to enable calling web service only from localhost and to disable calling web service from outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes very much, you can open the webservice to serve only the specified URLs by placing.
So that webservice will only send data to specified IP address.
In web.config under appsettings do something like below:

`<appSettings>
    <add key="YOURDOMIAN" value=""/>
    <add key="YOURSCHEMAPATH" value="WebServiceConfiguration\Schemas"/>
    <add key="YOURMETHODNAMEORPARAMETER" value="127.0.0.1,192.168.108.124"/>`
//other stuff

In your code you can write stuff to do various checks.

Hope this helps.